# Firebase Cloud Functions: why do some requests to external URLs fail?

Tags: javascript, firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to ping websites from Firebase Cloud Functions.
When deployed, it fails with small websites: it returns 10s timeouts, HTTP code 403, HTTP code 508...
NB:
-The Cloud Function is executed successfully
-No error message gets printed
-It works fine when running locally (with emulators)
-It works fine when targeting big websites (such as google.com)

What is going on?
Could it be anti-DDOS software blocking the requests from Firebase IPs?
Does the IP of the server running Functions stay the same over multiple calls?
Any help welcome, I am in the dark here...

Edit: Here is a minimal sample:
the function:

```
// file functions/index.js
const axios = require("axios");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.poke = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios({ method: "get", url: data.url });
        return { status: res.status, headers: res.headers };
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            return { status: error.response.status, headers: error.response.headers };
        }
        return `error: ${error.message}`;
    }
});
```

The client:

```
// file index.html
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="form1">
            <input id="input1" />
            <button type="submit">test</button>
        </form>

        <script src="/__/firebase/7.22.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/7.22.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
        <script>
            if (location.hostname === "localhost") {
                console.log("running in emulators");
                firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator("http://localhost:5001");
            }

            document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", async function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                const url = document.getElementById("input1").value;
                const res = await firebase.functions().httpsCallable("poke")({ url });
                console.log(res);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

An example of failing URL: https://fff.fr
When run locally, it prints:`{ data: {status: 200, headers: ...}`
When run deployed, it sometimes prints:`{ data: { status: 403, headers: ...}`
No error message appear, and nothing seems relevant in the response headers.

In the Firebase console logs, we can see that the function is executed successfully, it prints:

```
poke
Function execution took 1161 ms, finished with status code: 200
```

Comment: Pleas edit the question to show how you are invoking this from the client.  Also show any error messages from the functions console generated by your function.  There should be enough information in the question so that anyone can reproduce what you're observing.

Comment: I have added requested info, but I will build a truly minimal setup, though my issue lies not with triggering the Function, but with what happens with the HTTP request sent from the Function.

Comment: So you're saying there's absolutely nothing in the Firebase console in the functions log?  That means your function isn't getting executed at all.  If you do see messages, you should edit the question to show them.  If your function fails, the errors are going to be in the console, not in your browser.

Comment: No, I am saying that there are no *error* messages. The function is executed successfully. Client side executes successfully also. The issue is with the 403 as a response to the HTTP request made from axios.

Comment: (I have added the Firebase console log as proof)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm that some sites detect that my requests come from a datacenter and do not reply nicely. It does not happen when running locally because in this case my request is emitted from my home IP. Going through a proxy solves the issue.

Comment: I can confirm this, doing multiple http request with Cloud Function and will fail immediately on third request